# Android soundboard crash / MediaPlayer.stop()

Tags: android, media-player

I have a problem with my soundboard app for android.
When I test it on my device, the app crashes when I press the 8th ImageButton :.
Besides that I am wondering how I can stop the mediaplayer when I press another button.
Here is my code:

```
package nl.ingmar.soundboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton[] imagebuttons = new ImageButton[20];
MediaPlayer[] geluiden = new MediaPlayer[20];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    for(int i=0; i<geluiden.length; i++){

        int rawID = getResources().getIdentifier( "geluid" + (i+1) , "raw" , getPackageName() );
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("btn" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName());  

        imagebuttons[i] = ((ImageButton) findViewById(resID));  
        imagebuttons[i].setOnClickListener(this); 

        geluiden[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<imagebuttons.length; i++){
        if(imagebuttons[i].getId() == v.getId()){
            index = i;
            geluiden[i].start();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but start logging onClick with getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()) and see if there is a name discrepancy with what you believe your id should be and what it actually is in /res.

Comment: And you could also replace the loop by something like String fullName = getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
int index = fullName.indexOf("geluid") + 6;
int id = Integer.getInteger(fullName.substring(index));
geluiden[id].start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using so many MediaPlayer instances is a bad idea. My guess is that creating these many instances is giving you the error.You are **not releasing the mediaplayers** you are using to play the sound by calling `release()` and  you soon get out of memory. Call **geluiden[i].release()** on every instance when done.

I would also like to tell you that MediaPlayer is **not a good option** when you are playing *small* sound effects as the user can click on multiple buttons very soon and you will have to create a MP object for all of them which doesnt happen synchronously. . Go for the **SoundPool** Class which allows you to keep smaller sounds loaded in memory and you can play them any time you want without any lag which you would feel in a mediaplayer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html Here is a nice tutorial : http://www.anddev.org/using_soundpool_instead_of_mediaplayer-t3115.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not use so many nediaplayer instances... there is a chance that you may get Mediaplayer error (-19,0)  error because of non availability of resources.. so instead use a single mediapleyer instead of an array of mediaplayers.. in onclick create the mediaplayer and start .. check if mediaplayer is playing..

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 ....

if(geluiden.isplaying()){
 geluiden.stop();
  //create mediaplayer player with new resource and start..
  }
```